# Allow a close vote to replace an active close flag

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I was looking through my flags recently, I noticed a couple of my very old duplicate flags are (at the time of writing) still "active":

[image: Still active]

I now have the require reputation to vote to close, so I figured I should get the ball rolling by actually casting a close vote. However, when I click close, I'm told I've already flagged the post and am not presented with the option to actually cast a close vote:

[image: Already flagged to close]

If relevant, the two questions are [Insert python variables into rows of mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469982/insert-python-variables-into-rows-of-mysql-table) and [installing psycopg2 on Windows xp using pip and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496927/installing-psycopg2-on-windows-xp-using-pip-and-virtualenv).

In my opinion, this doesn't make any sense. My understanding is that all a flag does is place it in the close queue for other normal users to review. Since the flag is active, I believe this means no one has ever actually voted either way on whether to close or not. Essentially, all I did in the past was wave my hands in the air and tell people who *can* take the appropriate action, "Hey, come look at this!" And so far as I can tell, no one has yet paid any attention. Now that I have the ability to vote to close myself, I would like to cast an actual close vote that can count towards closing the question.

My feature request actually depends on whether one of my assumptions is true: I am assuming that since the flag is still Active, no one has ever voted for or against closing the question.

If my assumption is wrong, then perhaps the correct way to resolve this is that my flag should no longer be in the Active state. It should be marked as either Helpful or Unhelpful. Rather than sitting in my flag list as Active indefinitely.

If my assumption is correct, then I make the following proposal:

1. For users with high enough rep, remove any flagging options that can be used to cast a close vote. Users who can should be casting close votes in those cases, not flagging. (I make this suggestion mainly because there seem to be some concerns about abuse [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting), but I'm not really clear on how that's even possible.)
2. Allow users to manually "upgrade" their close *flag* into a close *vote*. If I understand the system correctly, this doesn't actually change anything in terms of how the question is closed. The close requirements are still the same as normal: either 5 close votes from users with 3,000 rep, a single close vote from a gold badge holder, or a moderator manually closing because of some extreme circumstance (in which case, it could still be flagged for that). My original flag should simply go away. I shouldn't get credit for a Helpful flag or anything of that nature, nor should I show an unhelpful flag.

Comment: I am sure it is by design. You didn't lose the ability to flag a post; why should you be able to both flag and vote to close a post? It doesn't matter that you didn't have the ability to VtC before and can now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters By flagging, I'm indicating that action needs to be taken. No one ever took any action, either in agreement or disagreement with me. Now I have the ability to take action myself. Why should previously flagging it for someone else's attention keep my from doing so?

Comment: @jpmc26 it is by design.  Please see [Should flagging a question for closure prevent close-voting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hm. I'll revise to a feature request, then.

Comment: Not sure we need this added complexity. This really doesn't happen all that often. And you have *already* sent the post through the review queue; changing the flag to a vote won't send it to the queue *again*. The community is either in the process of deciding if the post should be closed, or has already cast the verdict 'keep open'.

Comment: @Martijn It's more frequent on other Stack Exchanges, particularly betas, where the review queues don't move as fast as on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @starsplusplus: Sure, but you *still* won't have many people gain the vote-to-close privilege with many close flags outstanding. What this feature-request asks for is a lot of work for *very* little gain.

Comment: I've got a close flag pending from november.. but I agree this wouldn't really solve any problem other than removing active close flags.

Comment: @jpm I already suggested this on MSE - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222410/if-i-flag-a-question-then-get-close-vote-privileges-i-should-be-allowed-to-vot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flags and close votes now age away. As a result, you can cast a close vote once the flag ages away. You can also recast your close vote. This solves the problem of not being able to cast a full close vote once you've flagged it (before having enough rep to close it).