# What happens to all your pending flags when you reach 3000 reputation?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

As it is, after you reach 3000 reputation, you can't use the *Should be closed...* flags because you have the *Cast Close And Reopen Votes* privilege. But what happens to all the pending *Should be closed...* flags that were casted before reaching 3000 reputation?

Comment: Flag and votes are just the same from the database perspective. A row with a typeid.

Comment: The statement that you `can't use the Should be closed... flags` isn't exactly true. The option in the flag dialog is still there and you can use it, it just gets automatically converted to a close vote.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ It doesn't get converted, actually it just shows you `Vote to Close` button on the flag dialog.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355696/what-happens-to-close-votes-cast-if-you-lose-the-close-vote-privilege?rq=1

Comment: The pending flag fairy leaves a pending flag under your pillow

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The flags stay.

The other way around, your close-votes stay if you for some reason drop below 3k reputation.

Apparently this requires further clarification:
Whatever happens with your privileges, taken actions ***aren't*** affected.

Comment: But shouldn't the flags automatically convert to `Close Votes` or something?

Comment: @mega6382 Perhaps. But currently they don't.

Comment: @Stijn Then this is a kind of problem, because when I tried to `Close Vote` a question, that had my `pending` `flag` on it, it didn't allow me vote on it. At least there should be a work around for this, huh?

Comment: @mega6382 I don't see it as a problem that you can't close vote something which you already performed a moderation action on. You already did your part and now others need to do theirs, there are plenty other pieces of content in need of your precious close vote.

Comment: @mega6382 It's not really a problem. You cast the flag before you had the privilege, before you were trusted enough. Now you have gained that trust. Meanwhile, your flag has caused the question to be in the Close Votes review queue, where others will review it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when I hit 3000, I could go to a question I'd flagged and vote to close it. And then doing so marked my flag as being helpful, since there was a close vote agreeing with it. It could have been coincidence, though, I suppose.

Comment: "for some reason" why would they change to flags? SO doesn't cancel actions you made at a certain privilege level if you dip below that level, it just takes away your ability to use the privilege.

Comment: @TylerH that's what I'm saying. If there's a loss of privilege, for some reason, your actions don't get reverted.

Comment: @Cerbrus There are plenty of cases where reverting actions would be obviously bad; it would be nuts for comments to disappear or questions to reopen due to somebody losing rep. And there'd be all sorts of edge cases where the right behavior would be non-obvious; should items drop out of a review queue because the action that put them there got reverted? What if one person has already reviewed? What if nobody's reviewed but somebody has the review page open at the exact moment that the reversion happens? The design complexity is high, and the value low; that's a good enough reason not to do it.

Comment: Guys, ___I am NOT claiming actions get reverted!___ What's with the last few comments?! I'm saying that loss of privilege has ___no effect___ on taken actions.

Comment: @Cerbrus nobody's interpreting your post as claiming that actions get reverted. We *are* interpreting it as suggesting that actions *ought* to get reverted - that you don't see any good reason why they *don't*. And so people are providing reasons for the current state of affairs.

Comment: So, where am I claiming that _should_ be the case, @MarkAmery? The OP thinks gaining a privilege should have an effect. My answer says: Nope, that makes no sense, because losing a privilege doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Saying that X is the case "for some reason" - as you do about the non-reversion of close votes in your answer - usually carries the connotation that the speaker can't see the reason why X is the case. Maybe that wasn't intended here.

Comment: That _"For some reason"_ is meant to apply to the privilege changing.

Comment: @Cerbrus ah, I finally understand the confusion - you meant *"Your close-votes stay if for some reason you drop below 3k rep."*, but we've been parsing it as *"For some reason, your close-votes stay if you drop below 3k rep."* I'm with you, at last.

Comment: Yeap, that explains the confusion :P

Comment: Wait, Cerbrus, are you saying that if my rep falls, then every action I've ever taken is reverted, as long as that action was taken for some reason?!

Comment: @yshavit very funny.

Comment: @Cerbrus Right. The way you are saying it implies that you think losing the privilege to cast close votes should invalidate any close votes you previously cast when you had the privilege. But SO doesn't do this behavior for any action taken when a user had a privilege and then lost it.

Comment: @TylerH: For the fourth time, that's not what I'm implying. Nowhere am I claiming that that _should_ be the case.

Comment: @Cerbrus See my revised comment; I've edited your answer to remove the confusion.

Comment: What is there not to understand about _"if you drop below 3k rep for some reason."_? Especially after the ridiculous discussion we've had here, so far. ___Especially___ with the last line in the answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have edited your answer, perhaps they will understand now.

Comment: it's the same thing with close votes when you get a gold badge: questions aren't closed single handedly, there's no retroactivity.

Answer (score 2):

As Cerberus says, [nothing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260658/1394393).

But they do age away now if they're never handled, allowing you to cast a close vote somewhere down the line if you desire.