# If my reputation drops below the threshold after I have cast my vote but before the end of the election, will my vote still count?

Tags: support, reputation, moderator-election

Today I decided I would like to vote in the [current election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12), so I started looking for posts to suggest edits to in order to reach 150 reputation. Unexpectedly I landed on a question I knew the answer to, answered it and reached the threshold. Then I voted in the election :)

Later it occurred to me that my reputation might drop below 150, most likely through downvotes on or deletion of my one and only post (but perhaps also through downvotes cast by me on answers, or posts I had suggested edits to that were approved in the past being deleted).

If that were to happen, would my vote still be counted, or would it be invalidated?

Comment: I would be surprised when it wouldn't count anymore. When you do stuff which require a certain amount of reps, then your action(s) won't be invalided when you lose the rep later on. This is shown by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359048/what-happens-to-all-your-pending-flags-when-you-reach-3000-reputation) (flags won't change when you reach 3k reps) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399523/your-changes-are-identical-to-a-pending-edit-please-review-it-link-shouldnt) (old edits still need review even when you reach 2k reps)

Comment: This is a great question, and it's totally fine to ask it here on MSO, whether it is unique to SO or not. I am 99% sure that your vote still counts, since you were an eligible voter at the time you cast it. But we'd probably need a staff member to confirm that this is actually the case. As such, I'm not writing a proper answer. But either way, please be sure to vote!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Good question!

Yes, your vote will still count. We don't automatically invalidate previously cast moderator election votes if your reputation dips below the number required to submit them in the first place.

The same holds for [any other actions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) that require a certain amount of reputation as well.

Of course, if your reputation dips below the number required to vote in the election after you have voted, you won't be able to change/modify your votes.

Comment: Related to the issue we had in this election, shouldn't we allow people to change their vote, even if they no longer have the rep to vote so that they can chose where it goes?